# find and copy column value, column header will be same column will dynamic

Tags: vba, excel

I want to  copy few columns from different sourcefiles,  column position will be different from file to file but column header will be same

```
Sub CombineFiles()

    Dim Wkb As Workbook
    Dim WS As Worksheet
    Dim findword As String, found As Range
    Dim cell As Range

    Set myobject = Sheet1

    For i = 1 To 50

        Windows("Sample.xls").Activate
        Sheets("Sheet1").Select
        Sheets.Add
        ActiveSheet.Next.Select

        If Cells(1, i).Find(What:="Billing Provider", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt _
                            :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
                            False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate Then

            Columns("i").Select
            Selection.Copy
            ActiveSheet.Previous.Select
            Range("B1").Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste

        End If

    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: We need a lot more information.  What is the error, what line is the error,...

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply sir, please find updated comments

Comment: im getting application defined or object defined error

Comment: this references only 1 other file?

Comment: As you move across columns are you finding Billing Provider in different rows?

Answer (score -1):

You aren't defining these variables (add this to the very top of your code)

```
Dim myobject As Object
Dim i As Integer
```

Not including them when using `Option Explicit` would cause an application defined or object defined error.

**Edit :** I think you are confused about how `Find` works. Try something more like this:

```
Sub CombineFiles()
    Dim myobject As Object
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim Wkb             As Workbook
    Dim WS              As Worksheet
    Dim findword        As String, found As Range
    Dim cell As Range

    Set myobject = Sheet1
    For i = 1 To 50
      Windows("Sample.xls").Activate
      Sheets("Sheet1").Select
      Sheets.Add
      ActiveSheet.Next.Select
      Set found = Cells(1, i).Find(What:="Billing Provider", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt _
          :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
          False, SearchFormat:=False)
      If Not found Is Nothing Then
        Columns("i").Select
        Selection.Copy
        ActiveSheet.Previous.Select
        Range("B1").Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
      End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: sir i have added above variables, now its showing object variable or block variable not set

Comment: On which line? That should be included in your question as well.

Comment: sir thank you so much, i am sorry im beginner to coding.

Comment: Columns(i).Select

Comment: if i give Columns(i).Select im getting empty values, if im giving column("i") im getting values from i column not from found column